# The app gets forced stop when installed through .apk file but works fine when installed through adb in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

My app executes fine when i install through adb in android studio.

When i use the .apk file to install the app it gets installed but gives forced stop dialog whenever i open it.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: You need to build apk, and then try to install it.
Current Android Studio, makes up multi-part apk, which is bound to fail on with just one apk.

Comment: Add the logcat to the question, please

Comment: I tried to install through built apk only.

Comment: What error are you getting when install app through apk?

Comment: can you share your AndroidManifest.xml and what errors you're getting.

Comment: @Akash Did you try my answer?

Comment: @AbhayBohra Thank you. Working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable instant run from File--> Settings--> Build,Execution,Deployment.
Disable instant run and run it again from adb.
And then try to install new apk in your phone